# Прямая речь со словом "говорю" не в качестве вводного

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, вводные-слова

Я уж и так примерялась и эдак: то кавычки, то прописная, то ничего, -

как лучше смотрится:

> Тут уж я приказным тоном ему в спину: стойте, говорю, немедленно
>   стойте!

Или всё-таки вводное? Но это "говорю" никак не "источник сообщения".

Comment: Что было произнесено: "Стойте, говорю, немедленно стойте!" или "Стойте, немедленно стойте!"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Тут уж я приказным тоном ему в спину: стойте, говорю, немедленно стойте!**

Это **вводное предложение**: (я) говорю.

Или прямая речь: Тут уж я приказным тоном говорю ему в спину: "Стойте,  немедленно стойте!"

Answer (score 0):

Этот фрагмент лучше признать прямой речью — да так он и слышится, хотя сказуемое и по другую сторону от двоеточия, речь открывающего.

*Тут уж я приказным тоном ему в спину: стойте, — говорю, — немедленно стойте!*